# Display maximum match at first using like query in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

I am using a sql query as follow

```
string strPosition = "Blithe Spirit";
        string[] ArrPosition=new string[5];
        string strPositionList = "";
        if (!strPosition.Equals(""))
        {
            ArrPosition = strPosition.Split(' ');
        }
        foreach (string word in ArrPosition)
        {
            strPositionList += "CurrPosi like '%" + word + "%' or ";
        }

  string str="select * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like %"+strPosition+"% or ("+strPositionList +")";
```

In the  above query.I get the result as Book Name like Blithe Spirit,Blithe,Spirit .That is the output i need, but the getting output order as database row order.I need maximum matching that is Full matching of 'Blithe Spirit' as first and the remaining matching of 'Blithe' and 'Spirit' as next

Comment: i need both.output as full text search as first and splited text search as next

Comment: Use Oracle Text http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of another solution right away but you could union your results but first querying what is an almost exact match and then query similarities and join them using a union. (I have not used oracle (one of your tags) so I am not sure of the exact syntax for that).

```
select 1 as [i], * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like '%"+strPosition+"%'
union
select 2 as [i], * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name not like '%"+strPosition+"%' and "+strPositionList
```

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

```
string str="select * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like '%"+strPosition+"%' or ("+strPositionList +")";
```

Comment: this getting the data in mixed order...I need Full name as first and splited name as next

Comment: I'm not sure.. Once try this...
string str="select * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like '%"+strPosition+"%' or ("+strPositionList +")" order by BooK_Name desc;

Comment: Order by book name will get the data in alphabet order

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE (COLUMN_NAMES)    /*Specify all column names(tbl_book) here*/
  AS
  (
  SELECT * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like 'Blithe Spirit'
  ),
  CTE2
  AS
  (
  SELECT * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like 'Blithe'
  ),
  CTE3
  AS
  (
  SELECT * from Tbl_Book where Book_Name like 'Spirit'
  )
  SELECT * FROM CTE
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM CTE2 
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM CTE3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be close:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 1 as sortorder,*
  FROM tbl_book
  WHERE book_name like %"+strPosition+"%
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as sortorder,*
  FROM tbl_book
  WHERE book_name like ("+strPositionList +")
) t1
ORDER BY sortorder
```